# Writing Custom Kafka Serializer

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-kafka

I am using my own class in a Kafka message which has a bunch of String data types.

I therefore cannot use the default serializer class or the `StringSerializer` that comes with Kafka library.

I guess I need to write my own serializer and feed it to the producer properties?

Comment: Actually it is custom Encoder to kafkaMessage

Comment: Is it possible to run a Kafka application on i7 ?

Answer (score 44):

**EDIT**

In newer Kafka Clients, implement `Serializer` rather than `Encoder`.

---

The things required for writing a custom serializer are:

1. Implement `Encoder` with an object specified for the generic

   - Supplying a `VerifiableProperties` constructor is required
2. Override `toBytes(...)` method making sure a byte array is returned
3. Inject the serializer class into `ProducerConfig`

### Declaring a custom serializer for a producer

As you noted in your question, Kafka supplies a means to declare a specific serializer for a producer. The serializer class is set in a `ProducerConfig` instance and that instance is used to construct the desired `Producer` class.

If you follow [Kafka's Producer Example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example) you will construct `ProducerConfig` via a `Properties` object.  When building your properties file be sure to include:

```
props.put("serializer.class", "path.to.your.CustomSerializer");
```

With the path to the class you want Kafka to use to serialize messages before appending them to the log.

### Creating a custom serializer that Kafka understands

Writing a custom serializer that Kafka can properly interpret requires implementing the `Encoder[T]` scala class that Kafka provides. [Implementing traits in java is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637752/using-scala-traits-with-implemented-methods-in-java), but the following method worked for serializing JSON in my project:

```java
public class JsonEncoder implements Encoder<Object> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JsonEncoder.class);
    // instantiating ObjectMapper is expensive. In real life, prefer injecting the value.
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JsonEncoder(VerifiableProperties verifiableProperties) {
        /* This constructor must be present for successful compile. */
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] toBytes(Object object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object).getBytes();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.error(String.format("Json processing failed for object: %s", object.getClass().getName()), e);
        }
        return "".getBytes();
    }
}
```

Your question makes it sound like you are using one object (lets call it `CustomMessage`) for all messages appended to your log. If that's the case, your serializer could look more like this:

```
package com.project.serializer;
    
public class CustomMessageEncoder implements Encoder<CustomMessage> {
    public CustomMessageEncoder(VerifiableProperties verifiableProperties) {
        /* This constructor must be present for successful compile. */
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] toBytes(CustomMessage customMessage) {
        return customMessage.toBytes();
    }
}
```

Which would leave your property config to look like this:

```
props.put("serializer.class", "path.to.your.CustomSerializer");
```

Comment: How do you deserialize the byte array in kafka consumer now that we've serialized the object?

Comment: One suggestion: since construction of `ObjectMapper` is a heavy-weight operation, and since they are thread-safe after construction, it makes sense to create a static final instance of it for encoder/decoder. Otherwise construction will take 10x longer than actual reading/writing.

Comment: @StaxMan good point. I'm sure for most applications the best approach would be to inject the `ObjectMapper`, but like you said, for this example showing a single instantiation is an improvement.

Comment: @SamB. Yes, injecting a properly configured instance makes sense in many cases. Just wanted to mention this because performance effect is significant, and because code often gets cut-n-pasted verbatim

Comment: whether this method work with 0.8.2 version of kafka producer?

Comment: I don't think you need this for 0.8.2 because Kafka 0.8.2 has its own Serializer and Deserializer interface.

Answer (score 14):

You need to implement both encode and decoder

```
public class JsonEncoder implements Encoder<Object> {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JsonEncoder.class);

        public JsonEncoder(VerifiableProperties verifiableProperties) {
            /* This constructor must be present for successful compile. */
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] toBytes(Object object) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object).getBytes();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                LOGGER.error(String.format("Json processing failed for object: %s", object.getClass().getName()), e);
            }
            return "".getBytes();
        }
    }
```

The decoder code

```
public class JsonDecoder  implements Decoder<Object> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JsonEncoder.class);
    public JsonDecoder(VerifiableProperties verifiableProperties) {
        /* This constructor must be present for successful compile. */
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, Map.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Json processing failed for object: %s", bytes.toString()), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The pom entry

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Set the default encoder in the Kafka property

```
properties.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder");
```

The writer and reader code is as follows

```
byte[] bytes = encoder.toBytes(map);
        KeyedMessage<String, byte[]> message =new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>(this.topic, bytes);

JsonDecoder decoder = new JsonDecoder(null);
Map map = (Map) decoder.fromBytes(it.next().message());
```

Comment: How to create a instance of encoder? VerifiableProperties can be null?

Answer (score 0):

> I therefore cannot use the default serializer class or the StringSerializer that comes with Kafka library.

Sure you can.

For example, use Jackson or Gson ; convert your instance into a JSON string [or (preferrably) binary bytearray](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary), then use one of the built-in Kafka serializers.

### Other options

**Recommended**

Use the Confluent versions of Avro or Protobuf serializers along with the Schema Registry for your class.

---

You could also just use `ByteArraySerializer` if you write your class to a `ObjectOutputStream` (however, that is not recommended due to it not being cross-language supported).