# How to pass PcapPackets into Kafka queue

Tags: pcap, libpcap, apache-kafka, jnetpcap

With the below code to pass PcapPackets to a queue, is it possible to pass this into Kafka queue so that Kafka consumer can pull PcapPackets as such from Kafka producer?

```
StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder();  
Pcap pcap = Pcap.openOffline("tests/test-afs.pcap", errbuf);  

PcapPacketHandler<Queue<PcapPacket>> handler = new PcapPacketHandler<Queue<PcapPacket>>() {  
  public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, Queue<PcapPacket> queue) {  
    PcapPacket permanent = new PcapPacket(packet);  

    queue.offer(packet);  
  }  
}  

Queue<PcapPacket> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<PcapPacket>();  

pcap.loop(10, handler, queue);  

System.out.println("we have " + queue.size() + " packets in our queue");  

pcap.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Kafka supports storing an arbitrary binary data as messages. In your case you just need to provide a PcapPacket class binary serializer (and deserializer for reading).

See [Kafka: writing custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755976/kafka-writing-custom-serializer) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am late to the party, I share my tool: [Pcap Processor (GitHub URL)](https://github.com/slgobinath/pcap-processor) here if anyone with similar requirements finds it useful. I have developed a tool in Python for my research to read raw pcap files, to process them and to feed them to my [stream processor](https://slgobinath.github.io/wisdom/). Since I tried various stream protocols, I implemented all of them in this tool.
Currently supported sinks:

- CSV file
- Apache Kafka (encoded into JSON string)
- HTTP REST (JSON)
- [gRPC](https://grpc.io/)
- Console (just print to the terminal)

For example, to read `input.pcap` and to send it to a Kafka topic, you need to adjust the bootstrap endpoint and topic name in [kafka_sink.py](https://github.com/slgobinath/pcap-processor/blob/master/pcap_processor/plugins/kafka_sink.py). Then, executing the following command from parent directory will read the file and send packets to Kafka queue.

```
python3 -m pcap_processor --sink kafka input.pcap
```

For more details and installation instructions, please check the GitHub [readme](https://github.com/slgobinath/pcap-processor) and feel free to open [GitHub issues](https://github.com/slgobinath/pcap-processor/issues) if you encounter any problems.