# Do I need a custom serializer for producing JSON message in kafka?

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I would like to know if I need a custom serializer for producing JSON messages into the kafka queue. I don't necessarily work with objects while producing, 
but the messages that I get will be in the JSON format which I need to push into the kafka queue. The consumers will be responsible for parsing the JSON to the object they need.

Now, I would like to know whether I need a custom serializer to produce a JSON formatted message into the queue because after all JSON message is going to be a simple string.

Answer (score 2):

I think yes you need to implement your own custom serializer as the default one. By default the String serializer class is shipped with Kafka. You need to impement the `Encoder<T>` class and then override the `toBytes(..)` method.

[Here is a nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755976/kafka-writing-custom-serializer/24024119#24024119) that talks about implementing a similar custom serializer.

Comment: I don't get this - why would one need a custom serializer for producing to kafka ? It might be needed on the consumer side to encapsulate the logic for converting JSON message from kafka to whatever domain object the application needs. Am I missing something ?